# Firewall Problem When Using Psql on Amazon Lightsail

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, docker-compose, firewall, amazon-lightsail

I am using aws lightsail and met a firewall problem. I set my IPv4 firewall rule to " All protocols "
[firewall settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woAYC.png)
but I still can't access my database deployed on that server.

I can see two IPs on my light sail panel, one is Public IP and the other is  Private IP.

So I tried:

```
psql -p 5432 -U postgres -h private-ip
```

This can connect to the database successfully. But when I use

```
 psql -p 5432 -U postgres -h public-ip
```

it says
psql: error: connection to server at "public-ip", port 5432 failed: No route to host
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?